Настройка панели задач
Произошла интересная ситуация.
Я решил потыкаться в настройках в линуксе (EndeavourOS) и случилось следующее. Найдя в настройках панели задач виджеты, стал их смотреть.
Первым приглянулась штука, показывающая нагруженность ЦПУ. Нажал и ничего не поменялось (не увидел изменения). Нажал ещё раз, потом ещё раз. И так у меня оказалось 20 виджетов на баре.
Убрать я их никак не могу (панель тупа не отвечает), через консольку я поигрался и  также ничего не получилось. Переустанавливать систему лень и смешно после такого как-то и, вдобавок, хотелось бы разобраться с этой проблемой. Надеюсь, найдется решение моей задачи.

Можно удалить пользователя и создать нового.
Можно удалить конфиг из домашней папки.
Он может находиться в одной из папок тут ~/.config/application. Вместо application должно быть название приложения.
Либо конфиг будет непосредственно в домашней папке. Тогда папка конфига будет иметь название приложения, но начинаться с точки. Например ~/.application.
Удалив конфиг, можно на всякий случай отчистить папку ~/.cache для предотвращения рассинхрона между версиями. И надо перелогиниться.
После удаления конфига программа при запуске создаст новый, в котором по умолчанию не будет никаких виджетов.

Не нашёл, к сожалению, ничего подобного. Скорее всего плохо искал.

Ладно, поискал получше и нашёл нужный файл. Ваш ответ, на самом деле, очень сильно помог. Прописал rm -r plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc. Спасибо за помощь!

@KanekiKen Да если бы вы сказали, что у вас с KDE проблема, я бы мог точнее сказать какие файлы надо удалять
